# jquery keyup event being only called on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run a check on my database for existence of a username dynamically via ajax

I have the following document ready script:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#username").keyup(check_username_existence());
 });
```

And it calls a function

```
function check_username_existence(){
    $.ajax({ url: './php/user_name_availability.php',
         data: { username : $('#username').val() },
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
                  alert(output);
              }
});
};
```

Problem is that the function is not being called on keyup in the text input, but instead on page load. And it gives a proper response, the issue seems with the triggering of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis, change

```
$("#username").keyup(check_username_existence());
```

to

```
$("#username").keyup(check_username_existence);
```

Right now what you do is you call the function and you pass the result to `keyup` when what you want is to pass the function.